# How to get data from rs232 in Win 8

Tags: windows-8, serial-port

Is there any application in win 8 to get data from rs232 and save it as a xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of Serial Port support is certainly not a new one for Windows 8 apps. You did not indicate if you meant Store apps or not. If you did, the answer is here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/05/metro-answers-can-i-use-serial-port.html If you did NOT mean Store apps, then the technique has not changed since Windows 7. This is done in code, there is no native app.